# Dynamically adding flip cards in Angular HTMl

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I am retrieving a list of items from my database. I want to generate flip cards as many as the number of elements retrieved from the database. Is there a way to dynamically add flip cards with the respective item label on each card?

Here is the current code :

records.component.html

```html
<app-card></app-card>
```

records.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-records',
  templateUrl: './records.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./records.component.scss']
})
export class RecordsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

card.component.html

```html
<div class="tp-wrapper">
 <div class="tp-box" (click)="toggleFlip()" [@flipState]="flip">
  <div class="tp-box__side tp-box__front">
            <label style="color: lawngreen;">Institute Name</label>
            <label style="color: lawngreen;">Date of Visit</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-box__side tp-box__back">
            <label style="color: lawngreen;">Prescription</label>
            <label style="color: lawngreen;">Medicine</label>
            <label style="color: lawngreen;">Type</label>
            <label style="color: lawngreen;">Duration</label>
            <label style="color: lawngreen;"> Per day</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

card.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('flipState', [
      state('active', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(179deg)'
      })),
      state('inactive', style({
        transform: 'rotateY(0)'
      })),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('500ms ease-out')),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('500ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  flip: string = 'inactive';

  toggleFlip() {
    this.flip = (this.flip == 'inactive') ? 'active' : 'inactive';
  }

}
```

In records page, I wish to dynamically add the cards based on number of items[ Retrieved as a list] I retrieve from a database.

Comment: Why don't you just use *ngFor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `RecordsComponent`, add a property that holds an array of card objects with respective properties, e.g.:

```
cards = [{ id: 1, label: 'First Card'}, { id: 2, label: 'Second Card'}, { id: 3, label: 'Third Card'}];
```

You can update the property with a service call or any other way you need to once you retrieve them from DB.

Change the `RecordsComponent` template like so:

```
<app-card *ngFor="let card of cards" [label]="card.label"></app-card>
```

That `[title]="card.label"` is an input to your AppCard component, which you need to define in the class:

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
...
@Input label: string;
...
```

And then in your template:

```html
<div class="tp-wrapper">
 <div class="tp-box" (click)="toggleFlip()" [@flipState]="flip">
        ...
        <div>{{ label }}<div>
        ...
 </div>
</div>
```

You can pass an entire object into the input instead of just `label`, in which case your property would be called `card`, and then in the template you can access the properties like so `{{ card.title }}` `{{ card.id }}` etc.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion  but the cards wouldn't load and I'm receiving a blank page. Here's the link to the code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqhz44 Please correct my mistakes.

Comment: your answer helped me..Thanks a ton. ! But I have a small query...I have appended the image of how the cards appear on screen to the above question. Can you suggest me a way to show them in a row form starting from the margin.

Comment: @AkhileshPothuri Please remove the screenshot and post a separate question as that's a different topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please initialize your cards in ngOnInit method by implementing OnInit interface.

```
constructor(){}
  cards: any; 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cards = [{ id: 1, title: 'First Card'}, { id: 2, title: 'Second Card'}, { id: 3, title: 'Third Card'}];
  }
```